# Multi Flows to one list , Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two flows like this:
flow_a{List(a,b,c)}, flow_b(list(1,2,3))

when I merger{flow_a, flow_b}, it war returned [list1,list2]

How I can return one list like this: [a,b,c,1,2,3]

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Check `concat` and `flatMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` but concatenate the lists together instead of using the default behavior of creating a pair.

```
val combinedFlow =
    flowA.zip(flowB) { listA, listB -> listA + listB }
```

Comment: i'm very happy with your answer, tks

Answer (score 0):

You can use function like zip to combine the flows.

```
Flow1.zip(Flow2).collect{}
```

Comment: I tried this way, i want it return [a,b,c,1, 2,3,4...], not [a1, b2, ....]